# Запросы к серверу из метода в отдельном классе

Tags: objective-c

Я только начинаю осваиваться в objective-c, до этого писал приложение на Java для Android. Теперь хочу это же приложение сделать под ios.

В Android у меня был отдельный класс, который отвечал за запросы к серверу. В этом классе был один внутренний метод, который отправлял запросы на сервер и получал ответы. А тело запроса составлялось в других методах, которые уже вызывались из других частей программы.

Далее в нужном месте программы где я инициализировал этот класс, я создавал асинхронную задачу, чтобы UI потом не зависал (так как работа с сетью). И из этого потока я уже и вызывал нужный мне метод.

В obj-c я разобрался как делать запросы к серверу. Я в качестве теста в ViewController забил на нажатие кнопки выполнение кода, в котором делается запрос к серверу.

```objective-c
NSString *login=[_loginFLD.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *password=[_passwordFLD2.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://freescribbler.com/test.php"]
                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                        timeoutInterval:15.0];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    //NSString* params = (@"act=LOGIN&username=%@&userpassword=%@&clientcode=123123123");
    NSString* params=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"act=LOGIN&username=%@&userpassword=%@&clientcode=123123123",login,password]
    request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
        {
            NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"response %@",dataString);
        }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

Т.е. суть в том, что по нажатии на кнопку, достаются данные из текстовых полей (логин и пароль) и создаётся POST запрос к серверу. Приходит ответ и выводится в лог. Тут особых проблем не возникло.

Однако я хочу это всё вынести в отдельный класс. Собственно и тут вроде бы не проблема. Я создал отдельный класс, создал ему метод, куда вставил этот код. Разве что для эксперимента забил вручную переменные логина и пароля. Вызвал этот метод при нажатии на кнопку и всё точно также сработало без проблем.

Но мне надо, чтобы этот метод возвращал ответ сервера. Вот так выглядит этот метод. Я пробовал вставить return после вывода лога, но xCode ругается. Как мне сделать, чтобы метод возвращал ответ сервера?

```objective-c
-(NSString*)loginTest{
    NSString *login=@"***";
    NSString *password=@"***";

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://freescribbler.com/test.php"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:15.0];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    //NSString* params = (@"act=LOGIN&username=%@&userpassword=%@&clientcode=123123123");
    NSString* params=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"act=LOGIN&username=%@&userpassword=%@&clientcode=123123123",login,password];
    request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                      {
                                          NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                          NSLog(@"response %@",dataString);
                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: вы не можете запустить асинхронный таск и выполнить return после его выполнения - в этом и состоит асинхронность, что метод давно выполнился и control flow пошел дальше. Вам надо либо c loginTest передавать еще один completionHandler, который выполнится после NSLog, либо создавать протокол и передавать данные делегату. Ну либо как менее правильный вариант, делать NSNotification.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но к сожалению начиная со второго предложения я ничего не понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вернуть значение из метода с асинхронными запросами надо использовать блок.

На примере вашего кода:

```
- (void)loginTestWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSString *string))completion {
    NSString *login=@"***";
    NSString *password=@"***";

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://freescribbler.com/test.php"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:15.0];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    //NSString* params = (@"act=LOGIN&username=%@&userpassword=%@&clientcode=123123123");
    NSString* params=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"act=LOGIN&username=%@&userpassword=%@&clientcode=123123123",login,password];
    request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                    NSLog(@"response %@",dataString);
                                                    if (completion) completion(dataString);
                                                        }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

P.S. Посмотрите фреймворк AFNetworking, который делает работу с сервером намного проще и код компактнее. По сути, это уже стало стандартом.

Comment: Спасибо. Вообще уже проблема отпала, я перешёл на swift и нашёл выход из положения.